# How Can I Listing Files/Directorys in a drive (like : C:\\ etc..) optimally/quickly

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

I want to list all the files on a computer. Even on multiple drives, if the computer has multiple drives. Cloud does not have to be included, just the local files.

I have tried `recursive_directory_iterator` from `<filesystem>` (C++17). But that code is SO slow. Maybe it's not written optimally. So can someone help me on how to do this relatively quickly. It has to be able to store the file path in a string one at a time so the program can work with the file and when it's finished with that file, the next overwrites the string. It doesn't have to display the path like in the example provided, but it's good if it can.

The code:

```
for (auto& p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\")) {
    std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
}
```

When I ran this, it worked. I have around 450GB of data on my C: drive and lots of folders, and in around 8 minutes it still was 1/3 done or probably less. The program has to be run as an administrator unless it will trip up at certain folders/files. But that's not a problem.

Comment: Have you enabled compiler optimisations? Printing to the console is slow and is likely taking a fair proportion of your execution time

Comment: "*The program has to be run as an administrator unless it will trip up at certain folders/files*" - you can specify the `skip_permission_denied` flag when constructing the iterator. However, if the iterator proves too slow, you could just use the Win32 `Find(First|Next)File()` functions directly, but that is likely not to improve performance very much. If speed is important, you will likely have to go down to a lower level and access the underlying file system entries directly.

Comment: I have rewritten the code so it outputs it to a file which sped up things significantly.
And skip_permission_denied is needed because it tripped up even running as administrator but that's not really a problem

Comment: The program was able to finish around 1:20 m on my C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment, the thing that is mainly slowing down the example you posted is writing the path to the console, assuming that you did not redirect `std::cout` to write somewhere else.

#### A couple of benchmarks I tested with a directory that contains 2902 files:

**Default behaviour of `std::cout` writing to the console: 13253.1ms**

```
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

for (auto& p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\")) {
    std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
}

auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = t2 - t1;
std::cout << ms_double.count() << "ms";
```

**Redirecting `std::cout` to write to a file (out.txt): 34.0928ms**

```
std::ofstream out("D:\\out.txt");
std::streambuf* coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); //save old buf
std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); //redirect std::cout to out.txt

auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

for (auto& p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\")) {
    std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
}

auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = t2 - t1;
std::cout << ms_double.count() << "ms";
```

**Not using `std::cout` at all: 32.2823ms**

```
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

for (auto& p : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\")) {
}

auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = t2 - t1;
std::cout << ms_double.count() << "ms";
```

Comment: Submit an answer only when you will be proving a solution. If you are asking for more details use the comments on the question instead.